Collapse slideToggle on Click issue in jQuery
Look at this HTML structure
<ul class="block-navigation" id="sidebar-navigation">
  <li class="block-navigation-item">
    <a href="#">Parent Menu Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="block-navigation-item">
    <a href="#">Parent Menu Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="block-navigation-item has-child current-menu-item block-navigation-submenu">
    <a class="open-submenu" href="#">
      Parent Menu Item 3
      <em></em>
    </a>
    <ul class="block-navigation-submenu">
      <li class="block-navigation-item"><a href="#">Policy and Planning</a></li>
      <li class="block-navigation-item"><a href="#">Policy and Planning</a></li>
      <li class="block-navigation-item"><a href="#">Policy and Planning</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

Now I need to make submenu collapsible when click on <em> element inside <a>..
This is how I tried it in jQuery
$("#sidebar-navigation li.block-navigation-submenu > a > em").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();   
   $(this)
    .parent().parent('li')
    .addClass('testing-1')
    .find('.block-navigation-submenu')
    .addClass('testing-2')
    .slideToggle();
});

When executing above code it gives an error as below..

Uncaught TypeError:
$(...).parent().parent(...).addClass(...).find(...).addClass(...).slideToggle
is not a function

Hope somebody may help me out..

.find('.wp-block-navigation-submenu') - there is no element with that class in the HTML you have shown, only one with the class -block-navigation-submenu.

@CBroe sorry It was my mistake. updated my question.

The class you set on the HTML element is still prefixed with -.

Code as currently shown, should work fine ...? https://jsfiddle.net/zL2gp3ew/

@CBroe.. Updated the question... thanks for mentioned it

@CBroe, Thanks for your demo.. yes it is working fine with this code.. I real code I am trying to add this sliding effect to the submenu for the [wordpress navigation block] (https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/navigation-block/).. But with that navigation block this code is not working.

@Death-is-the-real-truth, yes its working.. but not with wordpress navigation block

Then we still need an actual problem description from you, instead of just "not working." Do you get the same JavaScript error, that you initially got with the code shown here? Then your HTML structure must presumably still differ, from what WP produces there. If you don't get this error, and it is somehow else "not working" - then perhaps the event handlers WP will surely add to this on its own already, might be conflicting with what you are trying to do there somehow?

You will get that error if you are using jquery.slim.  @CBroe 's jsfiddle updated:  https://jsfiddle.net/wyfekj8q/   Directly above your code, add console.log($.fn.jquery) and also add it directly above the event handler.   Report back here with the results.   As you mention WP, WP may include its own jquery in addition to the one you have added (if you have) which will change the version of jquery that's running inside the event handler.

@fdomn-m, Thank you very much for your comment.. It helped me a lot and also helped me a lot to solve my problem. Thanks again everyone for your time. I think it would be good if this could be presented as an answer, because Navigation Block on mobile has many issues on block themes in wordpress. One can use this as a workaround. The question will have to be edited accordingly.
